# iOS - Getting warning and not able to print

Tags: ios, printing

I'm using iOS 5.0.1 to develop an app.
I'm using the following code to print the screen shot of the view in my ipad app:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1004);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[self.view.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();       
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIPrintInteractionController* pic = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(img)];
if (pic && [UIPrintInteractionController canPrintData:imageData])
    {
        pic.delegate = self;
        UIPrintInfo* printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
        printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputPhoto;
        printInfo.jobName = @"PrintingImage";
        printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
        pic.printInfo = printInfo;
        pic.showsPageRange = YES;
        pic.printingItem = imageData;

        void (^completionHandler) (UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError*) = ^(UIPrintInteractionController *pic, BOOL completed, NSError* error) {
            if (!completed && error) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
            }  
        };

        [pic presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
    }
```

Its not showing the printing view and throwing following error:

```
WARNING: Calling -[UIPrintInteractionController presentAnimated:completionHandler:] on iPad
failed to find PDF header: `%PDF' not found.
failed to find PDF header: `%PDF' not found.
failed to find PDF header: `%PDF' not found.
failed to find PDF header: `%PDF' not found.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved the issue by using following methods related to ipad

```
- (BOOL)presentFromRect:(CGRect)rect inView:(UIView *)view animated:(BOOL)animated completionHandler:(UIPrintInteractionCompletionHandler)completion;    // iPad
- (BOOL)presentFromBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)item animated:(BOOL)animated completionHandler:(UIPrintInteractionCompletionHandler)completion;      // iPad
```

Comment: Bravo ! :) You helped me ! +1 ! I am amazed here - no one upvoted your answer.

Comment: For sample code fix: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-printer/commit/268f1b652d20e24c778c2387d387567db1964349